# How do apps like Facebook, Twitter & Instagram prevent users from having to relogin to the app?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, authentication, jwt

I'm wondering how the large apps out there handle their Api authentication. An example:

If I login to Facebook on my phone, I never have to re-login unless I manually log out, does this mean theres a token of sort stored that has 'no' expiry date?

I am familiar with JWT but I don't see how I could achieve this sort of result without major security flaws eg: The token gets hijacked & then the hijacker has access to a token that never expires.

Do they do something like: Refreshing the token on user actions? I'm sort of clueless here.

Apologies for the extremely board question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such kind of application when you re-enter in the application it will try to login but while get the token expired value it will regenerate new token by itself and make a call for login again in the back ground.

1) User re-enter in application with every web services check the session.

2) if got the session is expired.

3) make a new request for login in background with your credentials(your credentials are stored in preference)

4) again you can enjoy the application without interruption.

Comment: This sounds about right.

An example, if the user hasn't opened their app and the token has expired, it doesn't matter because once the app is opened, the token will be checked and then re-obtained as long as their username/password is correct? And we will be storing those credentials somewhere in the apps preferences?

Comment: @excojish exactly while you have working with any REST background it is sufficient, better and easy way to do it. if you like this you could appreciate ans with up vote.

Comment: You were very helpful! Thank you for your time :)

Comment: There are apps which give options of login via Facebook. They assures one time login. In that case user enter his credentials on Facebook login page and is redirected to application. Application have no idea of Facebook credentials but they assures one time login. They are doing this thing on the basis of long lived access token. @Concentrated_Attitude how this answer is satisfying?